# The action of $S_5$ on $6$ points

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I wanted to show that the symmetric group on $5$ points ($S_5$ as a subgroup of $S_6$) acting on $6$ points is not a transitive action.

Is this a valid group action?

It is clearly not transitive because there are more points to act on but I am not sure if this is considered as a valid example. thank you

Comment: Do observe that there exists also a transitive action of $S_5$ on six points. Namely, $S_5$ has six subgroups of order $5$, $H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_6$, and it acts on the set $\{H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_6\}$ by conjugation. For all $\sigma\in S_5$ and all $i$, we have that $\sigma H_i\sigma^{-1}$ is one of the $H_j$s. It is easy to see that this is also an action. It gives us a different way of looking at $S_5$ as a subgroup of $S_6$. This is somewhat unusual, and eventually leads to a construction of a non-inner automorphism of $S_6$.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1288812/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid action, provided that $S_5$ fixes an element of the six points, WLOG the sixth one. Verifying that this is an action is routine (and follows from the definition of $S_5$).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome, @mandella :)

Comment: Please don't forget to "accept" answers, @mandella, by clicking the checkmark $\checkmark$ next to them. (I've noticed you haven't accepted answers for a while.)

Comment: I had to wait 10 minutes to accept it :)