Cataloging the Core-free Subgroups of the Permutation Group
A subgroup H of G is called core-free if for every normal subgroup $N\subset G$ we have that $N\subset H$ implies $N=\{1\}$. That is, H is a core-free subgroup of G iff $\{1\}$ is the only normal subgroup of G which is contained inside of H.
I am interested in cataloging all of the core-free subgroups of the Permutations groups, $P(n):=\text{Perm}(n)$. Note that core-free subgroups are preserved under conjugation. That is, if $H$ is a core-free subgroup of $G$ then so is $x H x^{-1}$ for every $x\in G$. Hence I would like to catalogue all of the core-free subgroups of $P(n)$ up to conjugation.
For concreteness, lets think of $P(n)$ as acting on the ordered list $(1,2,...,n)$ in the natural way. Let $S_k\subset P(n)$ be the stabilizer subgroup of this group action at $k$. That is, $S_k\cong P(n-1)$ is the subgroup of $P(n)$ which maps position $k$ to itself. It is relatively easy to show that each $S_k$ is a core-free subgroup of $P(n)$. Moreover, they are all related to each other by conjugation and all have $\vert S_k\vert = (n-1)!$.
But what other core-free subgroups are there? Certainly, $H=\{1\}$. But are there any others?

Can we list them all?
Are they common, or rare?
How large can these core-free subgroups be? Are there any with size $\vert H\vert > (n-1)!$? [Answered below: No, $\vert H\vert = (n-1)!$ is maximal].
Are there any with size $\vert H\vert = (n-1)!$, but which are
not conjugate to the above-discussed $S_k$?

Even just an analysis for small finite values (say $n=4$ or $6$) would be helpful.

It's not too hard to prove that we can't have $\vert H\vert > (n-1)!$. First note that it follows from $H$ being core-free in $G$ that the way in which $g\in G$ permutes the H-cosets (call it $\bar{g}\in \bar{G}\subset \text{Perm}(G/H)$) is a faithful representation of $G$. Namely, we have $\bar{G}\cong G$ and hence $\vert\bar{G}\vert=\vert G\vert$. Not suppose that we have $G=P(n)$ and $\vert H\vert > (n-1)!$. Then we would have $\vert G/H \vert < n$ and hence $\vert \bar{G}\vert \leq \vert \text{Perm}(G/H)\vert < n!$. But we should have $\vert\bar{G}\vert=\vert G\vert=n!$. Contradiction.

Hint:  what do you know about the normal subgroups of $P(n)$?  There aren't very many of them.

Side note:  most people use the notation $S_n$ (the symmetric group) for your $P(n)$, and use the term "permutation group" for any subgroup of $S_n$.  Your question is perfectly clear though--thanks for including definitions.

Thanks for the point on notation, I am coming from physics. I know that the normal subgroups of $P(n)$ always include the trivial group, the whole group, and the alternating group. I would have guessed that it is always just these three, but for $n=4$ there is also the normal Klein subgroup. Is this the only exception?

Please ask one question at a time.

For $n > 4$ the symmetric group $S_n$ has exactly three normal subgroups: $1$, $A_n$, $S_n$. See here for example. So a subgroup is core-free precisely when it doesn't contain $A_n$. Since $A_n$ is maximal, that's not really a strong assumption here. Every subgroup $\neq A_n,S_n$ is core-free. So this question is really about all subgroups, which is too broad to be answered. See there for their (generally unknown) number.

Thank you for the quick answer! So core-free subgroups are very common, and there is not a good way to list them all. But what about my last question? Do you know if there are there any subgroups $H \subset P(n)$ with index $n$ besides the obvious $P(n-1)$ subgroups? I know there aren't for $n\leq5$.

@DanielGrimmer Those exist only for $n=6$.  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288812/exotic-maps-s-5-to-s-6.

That's very cool! But its a bit unclear to me what H would be in the link provided. Is H the Sylow 5-subgroup? And is the existence of this phenomena related to the fact that in S6 (uniquely) we have a mismatch between the automorphism classes and conjugacy classes?

@DanielGrimmer Yes, the exotic embeddings $S_5 \to S_6$ are closely related to the outer automorphisms of $S_6$; in fact each can be constructed from the other.  To produce $H$, apply an outer automorphism to one of the point stabilizer subgroups.
